# WCF weHttpBinding - specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7.5

i have searched the forum for a while now and tried a few different things, but i still am not able to call run the WCF from IIS5.

I set up passthrough auth. 
[Authentication IIS 7.5 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytjPW.jpg)

Here is the ASP.NET app weconfig:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="2000"></sessionState>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="d_torreggiani" />
      <deny users="*, ?" />
      <!-- explicitly deny all others, including anonymous -->
    </authorization>
    <!-- 
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    -->
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>   
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    -->

    <bindings>     
      <!--
      <wsHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_ISER_ProjectStructure" sendTimeout="00:25:00">           
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISER_ProjectStructure" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding> 
      -->
      <webHttpBinding >
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_ISER_ProjectStructure" sendTimeout="00:25:00" >
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"  proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />

            <!--<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>    
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8085/SER_ProjectStructure.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_ISER_ProjectStructure" contract="SER_ProjectStructureRef.ISER_ProjectStructure" name="WebHttpBinding_ISER_ProjectStructure" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>      

    </client>    
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and here is the WCF service web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and here is the contract declaration

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ISER_ProjectStructure

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Function RunProcedure(ByVal pPath As String, ByVal pProjectName As String) As Result

End Interface
```

On my development machine it works just fine, but when i publish it i keep getting this error:

> Operation 'RunProcedure' of contract 'ISER_ProjectStructure' specifies
>   multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper
>   elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper
>   elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle
>   property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

with this stack:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation 'RunProcedure' of contract 'ISER_ProjectStructure' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.]
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.TryGetNonMessageParameterType(MessageDescription message, OperationDescription declaringOperation, Boolean isRequest, Type& type) +972660
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ValidateBodyStyle(OperationDescription operation, Boolean request) +209
   System.ServiceModel.Description.<>c__DisplayClassa.<GetRequestClientFormatter>b__4() +83
   System.ServiceModel.Description.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetRequestClientFormatter>b__3() +244
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetRequestClientFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +435
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) +321
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) +259
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters) +432
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose) +102
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory() +46
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening() +86
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +570
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened() +117
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via) +477
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel() +58
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal() +48
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel() +464
   WebInterfaceProjectStructureRoot._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\d_torreggiani\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\USProjectStructure\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.vb:18
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

What can it be, i do not understand.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK if you are using 'wrappedrequest' you should have only a single entity containing the input properties.

So you should create a DTO class having input properties,then you should pass this instance of class in wcf method.